# Check if a value is between certain values in row of a file

Tags: bioinformatics, python-2.x

I want to read a file and extract only those files that contain a number between a range in the fourth column.

For example, in this line I would like to know if 5240 is between 5220 and 5240.

```
MTB_anc RefSeq  CDS 5240    7267    .   +   0   ID=cds4;Parent=gene4;Dbxref=Genbank:NP_214519.2,GeneID:887081;Name=NP_214519.2;Note=Belongs to the type II topoisomerase family.;gbkey=CDS;gene=gyrB;product=DNA gyrase subunit B;protein_id=NP_214519.2;transl_table=11
```

I guess I should make a list with each element of the line and index that position but I don't get how to search an int in a string.

I am using Python 2.

Comment: Each element in line is separated by tabs

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is good. You are almost there.
An error can be caught when converting a string to an integer:

```
lines = []
with open(fname) as fp:
    for line in fp:
        tokens = line.split('\t')
        try:
            value = int(tokens[3])
            if 5220 <= value <= 5240: 
                lines.append(tokens)
        except ValueError as err:
            continue
```

But it is also possible to test the content beforehand:

```
import re

lines = []
with open(fname) as fp:
    for line in fp:
        tokens = line.split('\t')
        if re.match(r'^\d+$', tokens[3]) and 5220 <= int(tokens[3]) <= 5240:
            lines.append(tokens)
```

For a more suitable solution, the question arises as to which values the columns can assume.